# Can the Flaming Sphere spell be rammed into multiple Tiny creatures that are in the same 5-foot square?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, creature-size, battle-map

The text of the [Flaming Sphere](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/flaming-sphere) spell says that "If you ram the sphere into a creature, that creature must make the saving throw against the sphere's damage".

Can I ram a Flaming Sphere into multiple tiny creatures, if they occupy the same 5' by 5' square?

I see nothing forbidding the sphere from being simultaneously rammed into more than one creature.

Answer (score 17):

## No.  Choose one creature to ram into.

The wording of the spell indicates a single creature.  Once it rams into a single creature, the sphere stops.  As such, it can only hit one creature before stopping.

> As a bonus action, you can move the sphere up to 30 feet. If you ram the sphere into **a creature**, that creature must make the saving throw against the sphere's damage, **and the sphere stops moving** this turn.

The others will take damage if they are 5' of the sphere when they end their turn.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, you can.

The wording is "If you ram the sphere into a creature".  The ability to ram the sphere is assumed to exist outside of the spell description, and is not defined explicitly by the spell.

I'd argue that if you move a sphere into 2 tiny creatures, both are simultaneously rammed by the sphere, and the condition "if you ram the sphere into a creature" is triggered twice.

Comment: Can you expand on how you'd argue it can hit multiple enemies if the first time it hits something, it stops moving?

Comment: @WilliamMariager I feel like your question would be addressed if Merudo added the word "simultaneously" to the phrase "both are *simultaneously* rammed by the sphere." But I'm not sure that's Merudo's underlying reasoning, so I'll leave it to them to edit.